# OpenSSL Wildcard Certificate and hostname Certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, request, certificate, wildcard

What CNAME do I need to generate a wildcard certificate and a hostname certificate in one.

Eg. I can generate *.blah.com and also blah.com, but *.blah.com doesn't match blah.com.

I want to know how I can generate a request to match both.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since, your certificate is *.blah.com, it will not match to blah.com. It will only match to single level sub-domain of blah.com. Not event to a.b.blah.com.

To match certificate both, you can use `subjectAltName` extension and mention blah.com in its DNS here. Now, it will also match to blah.com.

To see the effect of `subjectAltName`, open `https://kotak.com` and `https://www.kotak.com`. Browser will open both without any complaint. This is because, in `subjectAltName`, it has also mentioned `kotak.com`.